# Link fields of same values in different forms in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an MS access project with four forms one main form (BS&W Data) and three subsequent forms (WellTest form, LoopSamplers Form and WellheadSamples form). The subsequent form will be opened by a command button on the main form based on the value of a specific field (**Follow-up Method**).
I need to link three fields common between the main form (BS&W Data) and other forms, so by data input in these fields in the main form and then opening the subsequent form finding the same fields populated without re-input. 
The three field are **(Date, Well Name and Follow-up Method)**

Thanks

Comment: You wish to open a form to add data and find the fields pre populated, is that correct? is there any reason why you do not use the simpler method of subforms?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your form with modal property, you will need to pass parameters as arguments to the form using `DoCmd.OpenForm`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx

Otherwise, you can use the following syntax to access directly the control's value and modify it. Of course, it has to be open first to make it work.

```
Forms("subform_name")("control_name").value = ...
```

Comment: I would be very careful about opening modal forms.